# How do I setup Apache to serve multipe local sites at different locations?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to setup multiple local Drupal 7 site installations on my local machine.

Right now, I have a folder ~/Sites/drupal/7/{{various_drupal_sites}}

I'm looking to be able to access any of these sites at `site1.drupal.local`, `site2.drupal.local`, etc. The problem is that I'm getting a 403 permission denied both at `drupal.local` and `siteX.drupal.local` domains.

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

Listen 80


LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module libexec/apache2/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module libexec/apache2/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module libexec/apache2/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module libexec/apache2/mod_echo.so
#LoadModule buffer_module libexec/apache2/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule data_module libexec/apache2/mod_data.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module libexec/apache2/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module libexec/apache2/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule reflector_module libexec/apache2/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module libexec/apache2/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module libexec/apache2/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module libexec/apache2/mod_xml2enc.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
##LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module libexec/apache2/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule session_module libexec/apache2/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule dialup_module libexec/apache2/mod_dialup.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin you@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    #Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

#
# Apple specific filesystem protection.
#
<Files "rsrc">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile /private/etc/apache2/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile on

TraceEnable off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the /private/etc/apache2/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf

#
# uncomment out the below to deal with user agents that deliberately
# violate open standards by misusing DNT (DNT *must* be a specific
# end-user choice)
#
#<IfModule setenvif_module>
#BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule headers_module>
#RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
#</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@drupal.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7"
    ServerName drupal.local
    ServerAlias *.drupal.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@drupal.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7"
    ServerName drupal.local
    <Directory "/Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    ServerAlias *.drupal.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help learning to debug this issue or figure out the correct fix would be very much appreciated!

Right now, the only error I'm able to find logged is in /private/var/log/apache2/drupal.local-error.log:

`Cannot serve directory /Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php    ) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Please let me know if there is any other info I might provide.

EDIT: here is my `.htaccess` document for one of my sites in case that's helpful:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your apache log is telling you that it can't find the `DirectoryIndex` directive, so because directory listing is turned **off** you will get a 403 forbidden because index file is not set. You can add it here.

```
<Directory "/Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I assumed there was an index file but could not even read the directory - think you might be write though based of specificity of that error message.

Comment: @Panama_Jack still getting the same error message, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ficuscr yes and it appears he's using `Apache 2.4` and that is now `Require all granted` which he already has.

Comment: @YPCrumble did you restart apache after the change?

Comment: @PanamaJack exactly, I tried other response but not sure that's necessary anymore. Yes, restarting apache after every change.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Worth highlighting that it is 2.4.  I missed that.

Comment: @YPCrumble it looks like you are using `2` identical vhosts 1 in `httpd.conf` at the bottom and 1 in `httpd-vhosts.conf` you should remove the virtualhost block in httpd.conf.

Comment: @PanamaJack same errors. Included one `.htaccess` file in case that's helpful above. 

Weird thing is that there is an `index.php` file in each of the directories `.../drupal/7/{{directory}}` so I'm not sure why that error is coming up in the log!

Comment: @YPCrumble try updating your vhost with `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: @PanamaJack error has changed - now it's `client denied by server configuration: /Users/fitvalet/Sites/drupal/7/` hopefully close!

Comment: Try and add this to your httpd.conf `<Directory /Users/fitvalet/Sites> Require all granted </Directory>`

Comment: @PanamaJack I just follwed your comments then turned the setting to `+Indexes` per other answer and got things working! Thanks for your help. Probably multiple problems had to fix.

Comment: @YPCrumble Yes using `Options +Indexes` should allow auto indexing to work. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your Directory block in the vhosts file.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Think your httpd.conf differs on 'default' home directory.  Still sounds like a permission issue.  Turn on `options +Indexes` maybe while testing.